# Why I can't run my compiled Java file ? (.class)

Tags: java

I have compiled two files in out folder ([image], [image: second image])

Code in Main.java (source file from Main.class) is:

```
import gui_pckg.Gui;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
    }
}
```

Code from Gui.java (source file from Gui.class) is:

```
package  gui_pckg;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Gui { 
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame("To Do List");
    public Gui() {
        frame.setSize(500, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Im trying to run it with cmd (Windows 10) I'm typing:

```
C:\Users\jindr>cd C:\Users\jindr\Desktop\todolist\out

C:\Users\jindr\Desktop\todolist\out>java Main
```

And it throws error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

My Java Classpath is not broken!

Comment: You forgot to specify the classpath when you run the program

Comment: Try ``java -cp . Main``